# If $X_1, X_2$ are continuous w.r.t. $\lambda$, then $(X_1, X_2)$ is continuous w.r.t. $\lambda^2$

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-measure

Let $X=(X_1, X_2)$ is a random vector taking values in $\mathbb R^2$. If $X$ is continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure $\lambda^2$ on $\mathbb R^2$, then $X_1, X_2$ are continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb R$. I would like to ask if the reverse holds, i.e.,

> If $X_1, X_2$ are continuous w.r.t. $\lambda$, then $X$ is continuous w.r.t. $\lambda^2$.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: Certainly not. Take $X_1=X_2$

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you post your example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Delta =\{(t,t):  t\in \mathbb R\}$. If $X_1=X_2$ then $P(X \in \Delta)=1$ and $\lambda^{2}(\Delta)=0$. Hence, the distribution of $X$ is singular w.r.t. $\lambda^{2}$.